# Does the observed color of the sun change based on the observer's location?

Tags: sun-rays

A friend of mine visited Panama and claimed the sun appeared whiter. He's very color conscience and says certain shades of red looked different there. Could this be due to the position of the sun?

Answer (score 3):

The Sun of course looks less yellow/red if viewed through less atmosphere; i.e. when it is overhead, which it never is in many countries (like the US and UK for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much