# Does the perceived colour of the sun change based on the observer's location?

Tags: sun-rays

A friend of mine visited Panama and claimed the sun appeared whiter. He's very color conscience and says certain shades of red looked different there. Could this be due to the position of the sun?

Comment: You do not need to post the same question twice. Your first version is here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38537/24157